# Calling a python function that requires self

Tags: python, twitter, self

I'm trying to call a method in the class "User" in the twitter python api (Line 653): https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/twitter.py.
All of the methods require a 'self' argument, how do I pass it to the method? I read how to use 'self' but didn't figure it out.

I have used:

```
user = twitter.User()

name = user.GetName() #self needs to be passed here

print str(name)
```

This outputs "None".
So my question is how to properly get the self to send it as an argument.

I'm new to python and to the twitter api so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `instance.method()` is equivalent to `Class.method(instance)`, i.e. the `self` is passed implicitly. If `user.GetName() is None`, you have some other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` *is* passed; since `user` is an instance of the `User` class, the following calls are identical:

```
name = user.GetName()
name = User.GetName(user)
```

`self` is the implicit first argument, set to the value of the object that invokes the method, in any instance method.

Since you are getting `None` as output, this means `GetName` is returning `None`. If you had a problem with passing the argument, you would be getting an actual error in the call to `GetName`. Perhaps you need to specify a name when you call `User` so that `GetName` has something to return?

Comment: yes i realized that Name and other attributes are initialized as none. But the method VerifyCredentials() prints out all of the user details such as name, id ... so i'm trying to figure out how to extract the data from that method to pass them to other set methods.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't in passing `self`, as chepner points out. The problem is in how you are instantiating a User: you don't pass in a Twitter ID or any other argument, so the User object is never associated with any particular user. So it's therefore not surprising that `user.GetName()` returns nothing: there is no name to get. You should pass in an id on instantiation.

Rather than directly reading the source of a library in a language you don't understand, you'd probably be better off reading the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/).

Comment: i got your point as every method i'm calling is returning 'none'. but how can i get my id? there is a method called GetId but it's also returning none as it's in the User class as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if the doc actually had the GetName example.